# Scrapy log HTTP errors to database or pipeline

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I'm trying to get a full picture of my crawls in a database (mySQL).

So I need any `errback` stuff to get logged to the database.

Is it possible to pass `errback` to the pipelines?
I currently have it set up like so:

> Reponse -> (Item) -> Pipeline

When the pipeline starts it creates an entry for that crawl (through `open_spider`). That entry's table ID is then stored as a variable in the pipeline. Which is why I can't log the `errback` through the spider itself.

Or is there a way to pass the `crawl_id` ID from the pipeline to the spider's `errback`?

Comment: Ok, I've found out that you can pass variables from the pipeline to the spider. It's possible by using `spider.{yourvariable} = {yourvalue}` inside the `open_spider` function of the pipeline.

Still, I'd prefer to handle the error logging in the pipelines if there's a way to do that.

Comment: I imagine you already have an Item subclass for your items. You could create a second Item subclass for yours messages to be logged. Your errback function will than yield this another item with the desired message. Then you must have specific pipelines for each item and all pipelines must check the item type received.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that errback can also return items that would be passed to the pipelines.